# Can I Block Twitter Users from Appearing in Search

Tags: spam-prevention, twitter

I search Twitter a lot for information on a particular hash-tagged topic specific to the financial services industry. A couple of Twitter users have hijacked the topic and are spamming multiple posts per day using the hashtag in question.

I tried doing a block but apparently that only prevents them from seeing my posts. I want to block their posts from appearing in my search results. Is there a way to do this?

I typically use the Twitter web site directly or if on an iMac, Twitterific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Twitteriffic, to "Mute" users i.e hide their tweets from your search, follow the steps [here](http://support.iconfactory.com/kb/twitterrific/muffling-in-twitterrific-5)

But what I'd recommend you to use is [Tweetdeck](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com). It works on Windows or Mac as it's its pretty good client with good mute filers.

Have a look at this screenshot:

[image]

They won't be up showing on your TL anymore.

Comment: Hey thanks, that's good info. I really like the TweetDeck site on my iMac but what about mobile? TweetDeck isn't optimized for mobile and the iPhone's Twitter app, though excellent, doesn't seem to allow muting. It would be nice to find a way for my "mute list" to carry across devices (iMac, iPhone, iPad, etc.)

Comment: Previously TweetDeck had a twitter client too. On iOS try this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/echofon-for-twitter/id286756410 which is free and can mute users. If you are looking for an even better app try this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tweetbot-3-for-twitter-iphone/id722294701 there is a separate version for iOS 6 users too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is! You can include a filter in your search terms to exclude certain users.

All you need to do is use the "-from:user" search term for each user you want to exclude from your search. Make sure to include an "AND" in between each one, or else you might mess up the format of your Boolean query.

This might not be the best way if you want to exclude many users. [**Hootsuite's pro feature plan**](https://hootsuite.com/create-account?planId=2)  includes a "filter by Klout score" feature, and most noisy people have Klout scores under 40. Hootsuite also simplifies location-based searches if you are searching for the area around you. 
Hopefully it can give you some better results when using location-based Twitter searches.